# Django testing, mock valid requests to urls

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I have a bunch of urls in my urls.py file that have the login_required decorator

```
# Index Page
url(r'^$', login_required(views.IndexPage.as_view()), name='index'),

# Schedule urls
url(r'^schedules/$', login_required(views.ScheduleListView.as_view()),
    name='schedule-list'),
url(r'^schedule/(?P<pk>[\d]+)/$',
    login_required(views.ScheduleDetailView.as_view()),
    name='schedule-detail'),
url(r'^schedule-freeze/(?P<pk>[\d]+)/$',
    login_required(views.freezeSchedule),
    name='schedule-freeze'),
url(r'^schedule-create/$', login_required(views.ScheduleCreate.as_view()),
    name='schedule-create'),
url(r'^schedule-delete/(?P<pk>[\d]+)$',
    login_required(views.ScheduleDelete.as_view()),
    name='schedule-delete'),
url(r'^schedule-update/(?P<pk>[\d]+)/$',
    login_required(views.ScheduleUpdate.as_view()),
    name='schedule-update'),
url(r'^schedule-generate/(?P<pk>[\d]+)/$',
    login_required(views.scheduleGenerate), name='schedule-generate'),

# Client urls
url(r'^clients/$', login_required(views.ClientList.as_view()),
    name='client-list'),
url(r'^client/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$',
    login_required(views.ClientDetail.as_view()), name='client-detail'),
url(r'^client-create/$', login_required(views.ClientCreate.as_view()),
    name='client-create'),
url(r'^client-delete/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$',
    login_required(views.ClientDelete.as_view()), name='client-delete'),
url(r'^client-update/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$',
    login_required(views.ClientUpdate.as_view()), name='client-update'),

# And so on ....
```

For every restricted view I'm trying to write a test which ensures unauthorized users are redirected to the login page when trying to access the view. If possible I'd like to be able to achieve this in a single block of code, instead of writing a single test for every single URL.

I've tried something like the following:

```
list_urls = [e for e in get_resolver(urls).reverse_dict.keys() if isinstance(e, str)]

for url in list_urls:
    # Fetches the urlpath e.g. 'client-list'
    namedspaced_url = 'reports:' + url
    path = reverse(namedspaced_url)
    response = self.client.get(path)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
    self.assertRedirects(response, reverse('login') + '?next=' + path)
```

`list_urls` returns a list of all the named urls inside my urls.py file i.e. `['schedule-create', 'server-detail', 'schedule-list', 'schedule-update', 'index', ....]`

**The Problem**

this piece of code: `reverse(namedspaced_url)`

Where this causes issues is that each url has a different regular expression pattern, i.e. some take slugs some take pk's

so the line `path = reverse(namedspaced_url)` will work for simple URLs like those which point at ListViews but will fail for more complex URLs, such as those that point at DetailViews which require slug's/pk's, i.e. `path = reverse(namedspaces_url, args=[1945])`

Is it possible to temporarily override / ignore Django's pattern matching / routing to force a request to go through (regardless of passed args)

Or do I have to manually write a test for each URL with valid kwargs/args to satisfy regex?

Is there another completely different approach I can take to write tests for all my login_required() views?

**Update**
Using introspection I came up with the following monstrosity to solve my problem

```
def test_page_redirects_for_unauthorised_users(self):
    url_dict = get_resolver(urls).reverse_dict
    url_list = [e for e in get_resolver(urls).reverse_dict.keys() if
                isinstance(e, str)]
    for url in url_list:
        patterns = url_dict[url][0][0][1]
        matches = [1 if e == 'pk' else "slug" if e == 'slug' else None for
                   e in patterns]
        path = reverse('reports:' + url, args=matches)
        response = self.client.get(path)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
        self.assertRedirects(response, reverse('login') + '?next=' + path)
```

Comment: You should be able to introspect the items in the url resolver to get the named arguments. You can then call reverse with a suitable value, e.g. `1945` for `pk`, or `my-slug` for `slug`.

Comment: You again! I toyed around with this idea and was advised against it as it would mean I'd have to come up with sample values to match every regular expression pattern in my urls (which turns messy very quickly). I was wondering if there was a cleaner solution, as I'm certain somebody must have some across this problem before. But thanks for the suggestion! (if it's the only known way to work around this issue I guess I'll just have to do it this way)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to test something very complicated because you've decided to use `login_required` to [decorate the urlconf](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-in-urlconf).

Why not [decorate the class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class) instead? That way you can simply test each class to make sure it has the `login_required` decorator. This eliminates the need for mocking slug and pk regex values.

Comment: I'm not quite following, so you're saying that by moving the logic to a different place I no longer need to worry about the tests? (with the underlying assumption being I can trust Django's login_required decorator to do the right thing, i.e. and redirect the user). How is this different to wrapping the url with login_required inside urls.py?

Comment: @JackEvans you can either decorate the urls or the views - the end result is the same in that unauthenticated users will be redirected. In your case, decorating the view is simpler to test because you can just test that the view has the decorator vs. having to mock url `pk` or `slug` values in your tests like you've attempted.

Answer (score 1):

in the proect_name/project_name/urls.py
`urlpatterns = [
                 url(r'', login_required(include('app_name.urls')),
              ]`

This will apply login_required to all urls in the project_name/app_name/urls.py

Comment: This helps in a scenario where the entire app is restricted. But one of the restrictions I've been given is that in future new routes will likely be added that do not require a login. This also has the same issues when it comes to testing that each individual view redirects to the login view

Comment: put `@login_required(login_url="login_url/")` before every view you want restricted in views.py